# Unable to branch my tests using a variable in Postman

Tags: testing, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a collection with two folders, one for POSTs and one for GETs

[image: Collection]

At the collection level, I have set variables

[image: Collection variables]

And the following collection-level scripts to be run after every request:

```
requestLast = pm.variables.get("requestLast");
requestCurrent = pm.variables.get("requestCurrent");
statusGet = pm.variables.get("statusGet");

requestLast = requestCurrent;
requestCurrent = pm.request.name;
```

I want to always be keeping track of the previously run request, so I can return to it when necessary.

In the 'positivePosts' folder I have the following test script:

```
if(statusGet === 0) {
    postman.setNextRequest("resultsPositive");
}
else {
    statusGet = 0;
}

pm.variables.set("requestLast", requestLast);
pm.variables.set("requestCurrent", requestCurrent);
pm.variables.set("statusGet", statusGet);
```

The individual POST requests have no test scripts.

The results folder does not have any tests, but the resultsPositive GET has this test script:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
schema = pm.variables.get("schemaPositive");
tests["Valid Schema"] = tv4.validate(jsonData, schema);
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

statusGet = 1;
postman.setNextRequest(requestLast);

pm.variables.set("requestLast", requestLast);
pm.variables.set("requestCurrent", requestCurrent);
pm.variables.set("statusGet", statusGet);
```

There are no pre-request scripts anywhere in the collection.

When running the collection, I would expect this order:

1. postRich
2. resultsPositive
3. postAllProperties
4. resultsPositive
5. postMinimum
6. resultsPositive

However, what I actually see is:

1. postRich
2. postAllProperties
3. postPositive

I also don't understand why postPositive is not run after postRich.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can only currently read or get from the collection variables and not create or set them in the way that you're trying to do.

Comment: The documentation suggests it's possible. It seems bananas to not be able to change a variable across tests.https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

Comment: You can create the variable through the UI like you have done and reference it in the `.get()` function but I don’t think it goes the other way using the `.set()` like the global and environment variables do. That page you links say that it’s done differently too.

Comment: But I'm able to correctly modify the variables and retrieve the modified variables later, it just doesn't work for the first request.

Comment: If you were to take one of your single requests and do something like `pm.variables.set("some_number", 1)` in the Tests tab - I'm sure it would never set that as a collection level variable. This can only be done by manually setting this in the collection folder UI. Do you persist the variables when using the collection runner?